# Flex Builder AS3 Project migration

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I am developing a Flash game using as3, I chose flex Builder with an AS3 project. Now I am thinking that if selecting the project to be a flex project instead of as3 project I would have a lot of flex functionality like a swf loader,preloaders and the popup manager etc. The graphic components would obviously have been made in flash and used through the swc (avoiding the heavy mxml components).

Need to know what other developers think of this approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For AS3 I'd like to recommend FlashDevelop. However the MXML support is not as good and there is no visual editor of any kind available.

As to your actual question: Flex is the perfect tool for creating apps with skinnable, accessible, robust classical GUIs (with lots of forms, tables, controls, validation etc.). If that is what you need, go for it. Otherwise, don't use it. The few gimmicks you named can be written within a few hours or taken from countless other libraries. Like any powerful GUI-framework Flex is quite bloated and complicated. It increases file size and it tends to add a little laggy feeling to the UI.

In games UI should not be overly complicated and require 1000s of controls. It should be intuitive, contextual and blend right into the game. Thus maybe Flex is not the right choice for games (unless it's some sort of construction and management simulation where the user might need a kind of classical UI to manipulate all data).

If the game is not already too far in progress, I suggest you rather have a look at all the AS3 game engines out there to have a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using Flex will probably save you a lot of time and headaches. I say go for it.